# Is the category of PL manifolds equivalent to the category of topological manifolds in dimension 2,3?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, manifolds, topological-quantum-field-theory

Balsam and Kirillov write on page 10 in their paper *[Turaev Viro invariants as an extended TQFT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.1533.pdf#page142)*:

> "Note that in dimensions 2 and 3, the category of PL (piecewise linear) manifolds is equivalent to the category of topological manifolds."

This seems like a rather non-trivial result. Why does it hold? Sketching a proof or giving a reference would be very much appreciated.

Comment: In fact, every topological manifold in dimension $\leq 3$ has a single smooth structure.

Comment: It's also definitely not trivial. Perhaps see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96670/classification-of-surfaces-and-the-top-diff-and-pl-categories-for-manifolds and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296171/unique-smooth-structure-on-3-manifolds

Comment: The standard reference is the book E.Moise "Geometric topology in dimensions 2 and 3".

Comment: I don't think these categories are *equivalent* (the problem is with the morphisms).

Comment: @Tyrone: I do not think this equivalence should be understood in the categorical sense; rather, it is in the sense used by Kirby and Siebenmann (I do not think either one liked the abstract category theory or knew exactly what it is).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I agree, and that was the point of my comment, as it was something that had been neglected from the discussion up to that point. I find it frustrating that present day authors are not more careful with their terminology. I think your answer sums up the situation perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how this equivalence statement should be understood:

1. Every topological manifold of dimension $\le 3$ admits a PL structure (equivalently, admits a triangulation: In this range of dimensions there is no difference).
2. Such a PL structure is unique in the following sense:

If $M, N$ are PL manifolds of dimensions $\le 3$ then every homeomorphism $f: M\to N$ is isotopic to a PL homeomorphism. In terms of triangulations: The triangulations can be subdivided so that there exists an isomorphism of the subdivided triangulations isotopic to $f$.

The same holds for manifolds with boundary. Furthermore, the same existence/uniqueness holds for *locally flat*  (equivalently, tame) submanifolds. For instance, if $M$ is a triangulated 3-dimensional manifold and $S\subset M$ is a properly embedded tame surface, then $S$ is properly isotopic to a simplicial subsurface in $M$.

Proofs are rather nontrivial (even the fact that every topological surface admits a triangulation).

*Moise, Edwin E.*, Geometric topology in dimensions 2 and 3, Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 47. New York - Heidelberg - Berlin: Springer-Verlag. X, 262 p. DM 45.00; $ 19.80 (1977). [ZBL0349.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0349.57001).

*Moise, Edwin E.*, [**Affine structures in 3-manifolds. V: The triangulation theorem and Hauptvermutung**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1969769), Ann. Math. (2) 56, 96-114 (1952). [ZBL0048.17102](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0048.17102).